# ValueError: No axis named {0} for object type <class 'type'> attempting to analyse academic reference list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, text

Problems seem to be moving target. Once I thought one was solved, the next appears. Trying to analyse an exported csv file from an academic platform, listing top titles, keywords, authors and so on. Latest roadblock => view title of issue raised, code and result

Prepared file to be read and checked same terms appear in code as in file to be read, but code returns message that EDAT axis is not recognised

```
from collections import Counter
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

sns.set_style("white")

publication_data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\jcst\\Desktop\\Private\\Python data\\My_Collection_test2.csv")

publication_data.dropna(subset=['EDAT'], inplace=True)

publication_data["Year"] = (

publication_data["EDAT"].astype(str).str[0:4].astype(int)

)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10), dpi=600)

# Top 10 authors

plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)

authors_flat = [

author

for authors in list(publication_data["FAU"].dropna())

for author in authors

]

top10authors = pd.DataFrame.from_records(

Counter(authors_flat).most_common(10), columns=["Name", "Count"]

)

sns.barplot(x="Count", y="Name", data=top10authors, palette="RdBu_r")

plt.title("Top 10 Authors")





# Publications over Time

plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)

yearly = pd.DataFrame(publication_data["Year"].value_counts().reset_index())

yearly.columns = ["Year", "Count"]

sns.lineplot(x="Year", y="Count", data=yearly)

plt.title("Publications over Time")

plt.xlim([1986, 2020])





plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)



# TOP 10 Journals

top10journals = pd.DataFrame.from_records(

Counter(publication_data["TA"]).most_common(10),

columns=["Journal", "Count"],

)



sns.barplot(x="Count", y="Journal", data=top10journals, palette="RdBu_r")

plt.title("Top 10 Journals")



# Top associated keywords

plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)



flat_kw = [

_.lower()

for kws in list(publication_data["OT"].dropna())

for kw in kws

for _ in kw.split(" ")

]



top10kw = pd.DataFrame.from_records(

Counter(flat_kw).most_common(10), columns=["Keyword", "Count"]

)



sns.barplot(x="Count", y="Keyword", data=top10kw, palette="RdBu_r")

plt.title("Top 10 Associated Keywords")

plt.subplots_adjust(top=1, bottom=0, left=0, right=1, hspace=0.3, wspace=0.3)

plt.show()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm   2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/jcst/PycharmProjects/TextMining/Test2.py", line 23, in <module>
publication_data.dropna('EDAT', inplace=True)
  File "C:\Users\jcst\PycharmProjects\TextMining\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4572, in dropna
axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
  File "C:\Users\jcst\PycharmProjects\TextMining\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 361, in _get_axis_number
.format(axis, type(cls)))
ValueError: No axis named EDAT for object type <class 'type'>
```

Comment: the error shows `publication_data.dropna('EDAT', inplace=True)` , but the code shows `publication_data.dropna(subset=['EDAT'], inplace=True` , can you check which one is True?

Comment: Very good question….publication_data.dropna(subset=['EDAT'], inplace=True

Comment: But it tells me that the subset is not defined

Comment: Hi anky_91, did you forget me?...;o)

Comment: No Sir, its tuff for me to say whats wrong , `publication_data.dropna(subset=['EDAT'], inplace=True)` should work in general whereas `publication_data.dropna('EDAT', inplace=True)` wouldnt since the first param of `dropna(..)` is `axis`

Comment: OK, that is some answer, too…;o)